# How to transfer video from a smartphone (with microUSB port) to an external portable mini-DISPLAY (AV, HDMI, VGA inputs)?

Tags: external-display, video-out, screen-mirroring

I'm looking for the best way to transfer the video from a smartphone to an external monitor (used in cars, garages) to get a bigger picture.

1. I find this useful for dash cameras, and for entertainment with bigger display.

May I accomplish this with a OTG cable?

Your help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to mirror the display only and don't need touch inputs, I used something like this before to achieve the same via microUSB: [Rocketfish MHL HDTV Adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00AQ1W77C).  Likely you can find either an HDMI to miniDISPLAY adapter, or maybe a different cable that fits your needs (the one I've linked is the one I purchased and used myself so I can at least vouch for it's functionality; at that time, I believe I used it with a Samsung Note 4 - Android 4.4).

Additionally, I have seen wireless dongles that act as a receiver, but I have not personally tried these before.

Comment: I wonder if that MHL cable can work when the smartphone has not such feature in its specs.

Comment: @Michael Angelo Just out of curiosity, I did another search.  As your OP did not indicate the device's OS version -- _assuming_ that's a determinant factor for compatibility -- I was surprised I didn't come across an explicit answer to that [(example)](https://electronics.howstuffworks.com/gadgets/other-gadgets/roku-streaming-stick3.htm).  There is mention of a power supply adapter for the _display_ end in event of incompatibility though.  Update: before I finished this post, I did managed to find a list of compatible devices on MHL's official [site](http://www.mhltech.org/devices.aspx).